# Using innerHTML in javascript + back tick

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

i am new to coding and i want to use innerHTML to create a cart page but when i used it with back ticks, it shows nothing at the end. I tried
Thanks for reading me. I also tried also pulling the expressions out of the string and concatting them separately but it doesn't work as well.

```
function displayCart(){
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
  let productContainer = document.querySelector
  (".products");
  let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
  if(cartItems && productContainer){
    productContainer.innerHTML = '';
    Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
      productContainer.innerHTML +=
      '<div class="product">'+
        '<ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>'+
        '<img src="' +  ${item.tag} +'.jpg">'+
        '<span>'+ ${item.name} + '</span>'+
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="price">'+
        $${item.price} +
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="quantity">'+
        '<ion-icon class="decrease" name="arrow-back-circle-outline"></ion-icon>'+
        '<span>' + ${item.inCart} + '</span>'+
        '<ion-icon class="increase" name="arrow-forward-circle-outline"></ion-icon>'
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="total">'+
        $${item.inCart * item.price},00 +
      '</div'
      ;
    });
    productContainer.innerHTML += `
      <div class="basketTotalContainer">
        <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
          Prix total:
        </h4>
        <h4 class="basketTotal">
          $${cartCost},00
        </h4>
    `;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless you're using a framework you haven't mentioned, you will have a bunch of syntax errors in the console. Fix them...

Comment: _'"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.'_

Comment: Backtick is for template literals, and the expression you used with `${}` is a placeholder that's only supported by template literals.

Answer (score 2):

As Choz said, assuming that you are not using a javascript Framework you are trying to use `${}` to define your variables inside a string, this type of variable referencing is exclusive to use with template literals. See the basic mock-up below for further clarification. Your code is likely hitting errors due to the variable referencing therefore you thought the second part wasn't working ( in reality it just never gets to that point to execute the code )

```js
let variable = true;

let template = "<div class='123'>"+ variable + "</div>";
template += `<div class='test'>${true}</div>`

document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = template;
```